# Publishing is getting failed to specific target for specific component

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

We are using Tridion 2011 SP1, On our staging target few components are getting failed with error `Transport failed: Could not transport tcm_0-309224-66560.Content.zip using HTTPS` when we checked cd_transport log we can see error

```
ERROR HTTPSTransportConnector - Unable to execute HTTP POST
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
```

Same component getting published successfully on different target.  What might be the cause of issue?

Comment: Are you publishing over HTTP(S)?  If so, do you get an error in the IIS logs?

Comment: Can you tell a bit more about the Components that fail, is it reproducible, and how large is the published content (transport package)?

Comment: We have noticed that when we have .swf files in the transport package then it is getting failed.

Answer (score 2):

It might be that the size of the transport package is too large and is rejected by the deployer web application.

Answer (score 2):

I think you get a better error message when it's related to size (could be wrong - you can check the size limit in the cd_deployer_conf.xml).

That looks like your connection is being reset. Do you have perhaps a firewall between the CM and the deployer? Can you load the httpupload endpoint from a browser running on the same machine as the CM?

Comment: Yes we do have firewall, but the port is open to communicate between CMS and CDS. Yes we are able to access httpupload.aspx from CMS server.

Comment: I would recommend working with your firewall team, the error suggests the connection is being "cut" half-way through transport of the package.

Answer (score 0):

**Verify following:**

1) The other target on which the publishing is successful is on the same machine or on the other machine - If they are on different machine, verify the settings/config and most important the version of the JDK/JRE over there

2) Verify with the system admin team if there is some rule put up for the extension of your output component presentation

3) verify the size of the output transport package vs the max size limit defined in the deployer config

4) Use tools like fiddler etc. to monitor the complete publishing process and check for any hint

5) I hope you are checking your logs at TRACE or INFO level...and the above error is the only relevant information and no other warning or debug level information is there in the log?